# Python regex HTML

Tags: python, regex

I am going crazy over this, i hope someone can help me.

I am trying to regex this url: https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/?count=50&after=t3_xxxxxxx where the x are numbers and letters.

The url is from an HTML file:

https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/?count=25&after=t3_319905

I tried this:

```
re.search(r'(<a href=")(https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/?count=25.+?)(")', subreddit).group(2)
```

but i keep getting NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'.

Comment: I would recommend looking into a scraper like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: yes yes i know, but for this i want to use regex. I am trying to learn why my regex is not working.

Comment: you have plenty of characters in there that have special meanings in regular expressions ... they need escaping

Comment: First extract (with beautiful soup as recommended) urls you are interested by using an XPath query to filter urls that begin with `https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/?count=25` and after extract with a regex (or an url parser) the part of the url you want.

Comment: @user2369869 Hi there, I'm /u/EchoLogic, one of the mods of /r/SpaceX. What are you trying to accomplish? I may already have done whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: @EchoLogic It has nothing specifically do to with spacex, just that i frequent the subreddit and so i used it as an example :p Basically i am trying to get a url of each page of a subreddit.

Comment: @user2369869 No worries! Take a look at [PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.21/), you'll find it a lot easier to grab the page urls of a subreddit by using Reddit's API directly than scraping it with regex like this. You'll find the task much nicer to complete that way :)

Answer (score 1):

Use an HTML Parser, like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). It provides you a way to specify a regular expression to match an attribute value:

```
soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile("after=t3_\w+"))
```

Working example:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/?count=25&after=t3_319905"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

print soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile("after=t3_\w+"))
```

Also see the must-provide link for regex+HTML questions:

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

`?` is  a special character in regex which makes the previous token as optional. You need to escape `?` in the regex in-order to match a literal `?` character. You need to escape the dots also but not the one in `.+?`.

```
re.search(r'(<a href=")(https://www\.reddit\.com/r/spacex/\?count=25.+?)(")', subreddit).group(2)
                                                          ^
                                                          |
```

Extra capturing groups are unnecessary here. Just a single capturing group would be enough.

```
re.search(r'<a href="(https://www\.reddit\.com/r/spacex/\?count=25.+?)"', subreddit).group(1)
```

Comment: what is the difference between .+? and .+ or similarly .*? and .*

Comment: `.*` matches any character (_except line breaks_) zero or more times. `.+` matches any character one or more times. Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) question to learn about lazy and greedy.

Comment: yeah but what makes it different when you add the ? after * or +